# Python: Error in handling logging in Windows OS

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I have below code which provides the path of my Log folder in the code. The code works fine in Mac machine but with Windows OS I am getting the below error. I tried with backward and forward and nothing seems to work. Any pointer is much appreciated.Using python 3.11

```
debug: true
log_level: debug
show_error_details: true
log_formatter: default
logfile_path: "logs/xyz.log"
```

> > Exception has occurred: ValueError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: *run_module_as_main) Unable
> > > to configure handler 'file_handler'   File "C:\Program
> > > Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging\config.py",
> > > line 573, in configure
> > >     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
> > >               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program
> > > Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging\config.py",
> > > line 757, in configure_handler
> > >     result = factory(**kwargs)
> > >              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging_*init**.py",
> > > line 1181, in **init**
> > >     StreamHandler.**init**(self, self.*open())
> > >                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\logging_*init**.py",
> > > line 1213, in _open
> > >     return open_func(self.baseFilename, self.mode,
> > >            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\ABC\OneDrive - GFFS
> > > AS\Desktop\POAS\app\logs\xyz_2024-03-22T14:32:04.187669.log'